# String is empty but still have length greater than 0

Tags: php, regex, string

I am checking for html tags in a file using this regex:

```
/<([a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?(.*)?)>/
```

The file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div">
    <p class="class">Hello World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the result: (which is what i need)

```
string(4) "html"
string(4) "head"
string(20) "meta charset="utf-8""
string(18) "title>Title"
string(4) "body"
string(12) "div id="div""
string(30) "p class="class">Hello World"
string(14) ""
string(7) ""
string(7) ""
```

There's some "empty" strings that do not have content inside of them, but **empty()** returns false, and **strlen()** does not return 0, what is this?

Comment: Can you post some sample strings?

Comment: They're probably null characters.

Comment: actually is a file i capture with the output buffer, and i just posted it.

Comment: and how do i check for null characters? I tried !preg_match with `/\0+/` and it didn't worked

Comment: Post the php code you're using please, more than just the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The output result you posted doesn't look correct if that is the regex
you are using.

If you examine your regex (formatted below) you will notice that the first 
character past the opening angle bracket must be alpha, it can't be anything
else. So there is no way to get an empty result.

In general, recheck your work.

This is your regex:

```
 <
 (                             # (1 start)
      [a-zA-Z]+ 
      ( - [a-zA-Z]+ )?              # (2)
      ( .* )?                       # (3)
 )                             # (1 end)
 >
```

This is the output, based on the input you posted.

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 17 , len 6 ) 
<html>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 18 , len 4 ) 
html  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 22 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 25 , len 6 ) 
<head>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 26 , len 4 ) 
head  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 30 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 35 , len 22 ) 
<meta charset="utf-8">  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 36 , len 20 ) 
meta charset="utf-8"  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 40 , len 16 ) 
 charset="utf-8"  

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 61 , len 20 ) 
<title>Title</title>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 62 , len 18 ) 
title>Title</title  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 67 , len 13 ) 
>Title</title  

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 92 , len 6 ) 
<body>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 93 , len 4 ) 
body  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 97 , len 0 )  EMPTY 

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 100 , len 14 ) 
<div id="div">  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 101 , len 12 ) 
div id="div"  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 104 , len 9 ) 
 id="div"  

-----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 120 , len 32 ) 
<p class="class">Hello World</p>  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 121 , len 30 ) 
p class="class">Hello World</p  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 122 , len 29 ) 
 class="class">Hello World</p
```